# Rails 3, windows, Paperclip can't make thumbnails

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

So I am using windows 7, Rails 3, latest paperclip gem and ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q16 (tested in cmd), my PATH environment is updated.

**Model**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :user_id, :file
  has_attached_file :file, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :storage => :filesystem

  belongs_to :user

  #validations
  validates_attachment_presence :file
  validates_attachment_size :file, :less_than => 4.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => [ 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/x-png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/jpg' ]
end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for(@image, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |image| %>

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= image.label :description, "Description", :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-prepend">
          <%= image.text_field :description %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= image.label :file, "Image", :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-prepend">
          <%= image.file_field :file %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%= image.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= image.submit "Upload Image", :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-medium' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**My paperclip.rb in initializers**

```
require "paperclip"
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q16'
Paperclip.options[:swallow_stderr] = false
Paperclip.options[:whiny_thumbnails] = true
```

Everything is working fine without cropping (:styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }). But when I want to make thumbnails Paperclip throws this error

```
Command :: identify -format %wx%h "C:/Users/Zaraka/AppData/Local/Temp/DSCN630520120519-7696-18l3nw5.JPG[0]"
Command :: convert "C:/Users/Zaraka/AppData/Local/Temp/DSCN630520120519-7696-18l3nw5.JPG[0]" -resize "300x300>" "C:/Users/Zaraka/AppData/Local/Temp/DSCN630520120519-7696-18l3nw520120519-7696-1p8rcsr"
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Error: There was an error processing the thumbnail for DSCN630520120519-7696-18l3nw5>
Command :: identify -format %wx%h "C:/Users/Zaraka/AppData/Local/Temp/DSCN630520120519-7696-18l3nw5.JPG[0]"
Command :: convert "C:/Users/Zaraka/AppData/Local/Temp/DSCN630520120519-7696-18l3nw5.JPG[0]" -resize "100x100>" "C:/Users/Zaraka/AppData/Local/Temp/DSCN630520120519-7696-18l3nw520120519-7696-tx3bmo"
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Error: There was an error processing the thumbnail for DSCN630520120519-7696-18l3nw5>
```

I figured out that uploaded image isn't even in temp folder, so those created images just have 0 bytes. I'm completely stuck here dunno if something wrong is with paperclip or image upload. 
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I really have no idea what just happened but now resizing works! Now I have different problem, files with latin2 characters (like ěščřžýáíé) won't upload, it's "throwing is not recognized by the 'identify' command" error. I tried put that file in cmd and everything works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably means you're not pointing to IM properly. Either you don't have it installed yet or just not finding it as expected. Use double backslashes instead: `'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q16'`. (In order to avoid white spaces you can also use 8.3 filenames system to identify the path with regular slashes.)

If you're using the last version of Paperclip (3.1.4), on Windows I recommend you to install File package from GnuWin32. Please see this post: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/926.

Finally, in order to support non-English characters in filenames, you might want to monkey patch Cocaine. I put a cocaine_path.rb between my initializers. Be aware that 'iso-8859-1' might not be the proper encoding for you.

**cocaine_pacth.rb:**

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM == "i386-mingw32"
  module Cocaine
    class CommandLine
      def run
        output = ''
        begin
          with_modified_path do
            @logger.info("\e[32mCommand\e[0m :: #{command}") if @logger
            ec = Encoding::Converter.new("utf-8", "iso-8859-1")
            output = self.class.send(:'`', ec.convert(command.encode('UTF-8')))
          end
        rescue Errno::ENOENT
          raise Cocaine::CommandNotFoundError
        end
        if $?.exitstatus == 127
          raise Cocaine::CommandNotFoundError
        end
        unless @expected_outcodes.include?($?.exitstatus)
          raise Cocaine::ExitStatusError, "Command '#{command}' returned #{$?.exitstatus}. Expected #{@expected_outcodes.join(", ")}"
        end
        output
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This covers all the issues I have had with Paperclip on Windows in the last days. I hope it helps.

Comment: I moved development to Linux, developing rails apps under Windows can be difficult sometimes....